# Need to remove spaces from a given string using filter

Tags: python, python-2.7, filter

I was under the impression that the following code:

```
filter(None,"Stack Overflow")
```

would return:

```
"StackOverflow"
```

But that did not happen when I was used Python (2.7). Could anybody tell me why it is so?

Comment: on python 3, `filter` returns a generator object. So you have to use `''.join(filter...`

Comment: see [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) `If function is None, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of iterable that are false are removed.`

Answer (score 5):

You appear to want to filter out the space, however a space isn't `False` (which the `None` searches for), so explicitly check for a space:

```
filter(lambda x: x!=' ',"Stack Overflow")
```

Furthermore, if you are only dealing with strings, don't forget `replace`:

```
"Stack Overflow".replace(' ', '')
```

Comment: moreover, filter needs join in python 3. Less interesting now.

Comment: Right - cos you get a a generator back. However this is tagged 2.7, but worth pointing out

Answer (score 2):

The help for `filter` states

> Return those items of sequence for which function(item) is true.  If
>       function is None, return the items that are true.

The boolean value of a space is `True` so it is not removed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a function that replaces ' ':

```
filter(lambda x: x != ' ', 'Stack Overflow')
```

See the documentation for [filter](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#filter).

When no function is specified it just compares whether the element is truthy which is the case for ' ' as well as for any other character. For a better understanding see this example where `None` is a falsy value and is therefore removed from the list:

```
filter(None, ['S', 't', 'a', 'c', 'k', None, 'O', 'v', 'e', 'r', 'f', 'l', 'o', 'w'])
```